# What do exiles do in Endless Space 2

Tags: endless-space-2

Twice now, when one of my scout ships has launched a probe at a curiosity on a remote planet, the popup said I had been awarded with Amoeba Exiles. Where do these exiles go?

I thought they might appear as population somewhere in my empire, but they're not on any of my planets. They don't appear as anomalies/resources in the system I found them on either. There's no colonized planets in that system.

Answer (score 7):

They do appear as population, it just takes some time.

When you find an exile, you'll notice a little civilian ship with them on it. They automatically move to your nearst system with free population slots and join that colony.

Comment: Yes, you can actually see that ship leaving if you watch closely.  Also, you should be able to see it while it's on the way to your planet.  It is small, and looks like a regular logistics ship.  Once it gets there, you get the population.